# Will alerts be configured to run with your specific candle type?

Tags: pine-script

I am setting up customer alerts on TradingView using a script I wrote in the Pine Editor.  Currently it is profitable when the chart is set to use the Heikin Ashi candle style but its horrible using the traditional bars.  My question is when I set the alert with Heikin Ashi as my bar pattern, does TradingView use that when it calculates the script?

Comment: Personally if your using the heikinashi() function to calculate then it shouldn't change. But if you provide code it would be easier to understand. Surely by back testing you would understand if there is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the alert on an HA chart, that's what the alert will use to calculate. You should not be issuing buy/sell alerts on HA charts because they produce unrealistic results, as you have noticed. See here if you need to understand more:

- In the Help Center: [Strategy produces unrealistic results on non-standard chart types (Heikin Ashi, Renko, etc.)](https://www.tradingview.com/?solution=43000481029)
- From PineCoders: [Backtesting on Non-Standard Charts: Caution!](https://www.tradingview.com/script/q9laJNG9-Backtesting-on-Non-Standard-Charts-Caution-PineCoders-FAQ/)